# Why Store Secret Access Tokens in Environment Variable If Environment Variable Won't be Available When App Ships

Tags: android, gradle, mapbox, secret-key

The following instructions from [this mapbox tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/) have me confused. What happens when I ship my app? How will the users have access to the mapbox if the secret token is stored in an environment variable in my local machine only?

[image: Mapbox Instructions for Storing Secret Token]

What am I not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

The build scripts will pick up the token and use it at build time.

For that specific token it seems to be used only to access a maven repository.
In the general case the secret could also be included in the built binary, or whatever is needed. The main idea is to not have secrets stored in the source repository itself.